# How to correctly redefine print in Lua 5.3?

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

I frequently use `print` function for debugging in conjunction with `os.exit()`. I don't want to type `os.exit()` each time I use `print`, so I want to redefine this function.

```
> function pprint(...)
>> for _,a in ipairs(arg) do
>> print(a)
>> end
>> os.exit()
>> end


> pprint('hello',1,2,3)
hello
1
2
3
[johndoe@dell-john ~]$
```

Although this works in **Lua 5.1**, it does not work in **Lua 5.3** and, for some reason, [Torch](http://torch.ch/). I looked up the Lua 5.3 docs for "triple dots" expression but couldn't find the reference on how to access `...` arguments. Can you explain what was changed and how to redefine `print` for Lua 5.3?

Comment: `for _,a in ipairs{...} do`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic creation of the `arg` table for vararg functions was deprecated in Lua 5.1 and removed in Lua 5.2.

As mentioned by Egor, use

```
for _,a in ipairs({...}) do
```

instead of

```
for _,a in ipairs(arg) do
```

Or add

```
local arg={...}
```

at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`for _,a in ipairs({...}) do` is **wrong** ,it does not support `nil`

right rewrite

```lua
local arg = table.pack(...)
for i = 1 ,arg.n do
    old_print(arg[i])
end
```